PgAdmin can't find the binaries path
When trying to validate the path of the bin directory for PostgreSQL 12, PgAdmin cannot find the related files.
I'm using Ubuntu 22 OS.
I have already installed postgresql-client-12 using the following command:
tomas@tomas-efficast:~$ sudo apt install postgresql-client-12
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
postgresql-client-12 is already at the latest version (12.20-1.pgdg22.04+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove, and 0 not upgraded.

I also tried adding the path with the command:
export PATH="$HOME/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin:$PATH"

I also thought it might be a permissions issue, so I assigned postgres as the owner of /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin using:
sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin

Yet, PgAdmin still shows the following message:


I also tried using /usr/bin and the pg_dump, pg_restore files from there (which I believe are from PostgreSQL 15 because I have that version installed as well), but it still doesn’t work.
However, I need to use pg_dump in version 12 because that’s the version used by the database I’m connected to.


What is the exact error message you get? Add as text update to question text. 2) pg_dump and pg_restore are backwards compatible, so there should not be an issue using the Postgres 15 versions of those clients. 3) Is the Postgres 12 instance local or remote?


The Postgres instance I'm trying to back up is remote and is version 12. On my local computer, I have both Postgres 15 and 12 installed. I’m uploading an image with the message PgAdmin returns when I try to set the binaries (I forgot to do it when I created the post).


Are you installing Postgres from the PGDG repo's? 2) Are there actually files in /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/? 3) If yes to 1) try using pg_dump from the CLI directly like: pg_dump --cluster 12/main  -d database_name -U user_name .... This assumes the Postgres  12 instance was created with the default cluster name of main.


Yes, the files are located there. I will try using the pg_dump command directly for the related tables from the SQL scripts tabs in PgAdmin and see what happens. Thank you very much for your help.
